# Choosing analytics location in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

when I create a project in firebase, I am offered to choose analytics location
When you click on the question mark, they write: "This represents the country/region of your organization. This does not affect where Google may process and store Customer Data for Firebase."

Question: If I want to upload an application to the appstore for different countries, for example, America, Russia and European countries, then I will have to connect several firebase projects for different countries at once? How can I connect one firebase for all countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but it seems you are mixing up things.

When setting up services on your Google Cloud Project, you may choose their location, this means that the service you are activating will be hosted on a specific place, and thus people from other countries may have bigger latency accessing your services. Example, if you host a service in North America, the latency for users from Asia will be higher.

That will not geographically restrict or limit users to access your service, web app, or API services.

If you want to restrict users from specific countries from downloading your app, on the app store you have settings that will do that for you.

The short answer: no, you don't need multiple projects for multiple countries.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, otherwise I couldn't find much information at this point.